# WM_MOUSEMOVE GET_X_LPARAM AND GET_Y_LPARAM Catch wrong Coordinates

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, mousemove

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        if (wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
        {
            cout << "X : " << GET_X_LPARAM(lParam) << " Y: " << GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) << "\n";
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hMSHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

    int _tmain() {
        HMODULE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
        hMSHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseProc, hInstance, NULL);

        MSG Msg;

        while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0)) { DispatchMessage(&Msg); }
        ::ReleaseDC(0, dc);

        return 0;
    }
```

result = Always return wrong coordinates,

example =  X = -1844, Y = 79,

X = -1556 Y = 271,

X = -1028 Y = 91

...

Value is changing when every launch

somebody can help me?

Comment: How many monitors do you have?

Comment: only one monitor i have

Comment: You need to convert lParam to MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT pointer because you set to WH_MOUSE_LL. This hook type install hook procedure, and lparam in callback is pointer of data struct

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms644986(v=vs.85).aspx you can see in MSDN, In MSDN, lparam is 'A pointer to an MSLLHOOKSTRUCT structure.'

Answer (score 6):

The `lParam` parameter of `MouseProc` is not identical to the `lParam` parameter for `WM_MOUSEMOVE`.  It is a `MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT *`.

So, change `MouseProc` to :

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        auto &ms = * (const MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT *) lParam;
        if (wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
        {
            cout << "X : " << ms.pt.x << " Y: " << ms.pt.y << "\n";
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hMSHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```